# minSdkVersion Google Play Adobe AIR

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, google-play

I have tried uploading my Adobe AIR app to google play i get message below.

> You uploaded an APK that uses Google Play services version 4242000.
>   This will only work with Android API levels of 9 and above. This
>   cannot be published in Google Play unless you have set the
>   minSdkVersion in your manifest to 9 or higher.

I have set the minSdk version in my app xml like below

```
  <android>
    <manifestAdditions>
      <![CDATA[<manifest  android:installLocation="preferExternal">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>
        <supports-screens android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:smallScreens="false" android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
    <application>
```

So question is why am I getting this error? I have checked previously uploaded apps and they do have an API of 8+ and i am setting the minSdk 10 on these as well. It looks as though somewhere else is setting the minSdk value and the manifest is being ignored?
Does someone know where it is getting set?
I am using AIR version 14.0.0.125 could it be a bug in AIR?

Below is a list of ANEs i am using

```
 <extensions>
    <extensionID>com.chartboost.plugin.air</extensionID>
    <extensionID>com.freshplanet.AirAlert</extensionID>
    <extensionID>com.sticksports.nativeExtensions.GameCenter</extensionID>
    <extensionID>com.sticksports.nativeExtensions.CanOpenUrl</extensionID>
    <extensionID>com.freshplanet.AirGooglePlayGamesService</extensionID>
    <extensionID>com.codealchemy.ane.admobane</extensionID>
  </extensions>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution. i changed:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"/>
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
```

to

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
```

Comment: It works! Why would this make a difference, does the second tag overwrite the first tag, seem fragile.I had my tags opposite to yours, so if that was true the minSdk would overwrite the targetSdk

Comment: I had the same problem today when trying to upload an APK and this worked. I'm not sure why it works, but it seems there's a bug in the AIR runtime.